# Checking if a list is included in a property which is a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

**SCENARIO**
I have a class with a different number of attributes. One of them is a string.

**OBJECTIVE**
Check if a list of string is included in that attribute.

**EXAMPLE**
The string attribute could be a description of a car, just like:

> "Chevrolet 100 has 3000cc, using 250Cv. The 55/95 tires are included
>   in the price. Just for 2 PAX... etc ..."

And the checking list could be:

> "3000cc", "250Cv", "55/95 tires"

So my code would be:

```
         Class_A
int      id
int      price
string   definition

Class_A car = new Class_A()
{
    id = 1,
    price = 100000,
    definition = "Chevrolet 100 has 3000cc, using 250Cv. The 55/95 tires are 
    included in the price. Just for 2 PAX... etc ..."
}

List<string> checkingList = new List<string>();
checkingList.Add("3000cc");
checkingList.Add("250Cv");
checkingList.Add("55/95 tires");
```

As examples I tried:

```
bool sucess;
sucess = car.Select(p => p.definition.Contains(checkingList)).FirstorDefault();
sucess = car.Select(p => p.Where(o => o.definition.Contains(checkingList)).FirstorDefault();
sucess = car.Select(p => p.Where(o => o.definition.ForEach.Contains(checkingList)).FirstorDefault();
```

Thanks in advance mates.

Comment: They are called *Properties*, not *attributes*. Attributes are something else entirely.

Comment: Does `Class_A` implement `IEnumerable<T>`?  Otherwise how are you calling `Select` on it?  Or is `car` suppose to be a `List<Class_A>`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks... :)

Comment: @juharr. My true Class_A is more complex and it implement IEnumerable. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `List<Class_A>` named `cars`, use the `Any` method to check if any item from the `checkingList` is found within the `definition` property:

```
cars.Select(p => checkingList.Any(y => p.definition.Contains(y)).FirstorDefault();
```

If you need to make sure each and every string within `checkingList` is in `definition` property, then use `All` instead of `Any`.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like the OP might actually need `All`.

Comment: Also I don't know how you can call `Select` on `car` as it doesn't seem to implement `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi. I need all instead of any, but when I saw your code I realize it. Thanks again mate

Comment: @juharr. I was a bad example, sorry about it. Thanks as well for try to teach me... :). Cheers mate :)

Comment: @juharr I figured the OP has a list of cars